# Angular 5 Always load the cached version

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular5

**Angular 5** Web App - Always loads the cached version or old version i should push ctrl + f5 to get new version and clear cache.
i find this solution

```
@Component({
   selector: 'csj-app',
   templateUrl: 'app/component/app.component.html?v=1.0',
   styleUrls: ['style/app.css?v=1.0']
})
```

but i get this error when i build with aot

```
ERROR in : Couldn't resolve resource app.component.html?v=1
```

Comment: why are you adding url parameters to the template and style links?

Comment: Are you using the angular-cli?  If so, this will only be a problem when running a dev build. Production builds will receive hashes for modules and styles when using angular-cli >= 1.5.

For development you can set the browser not to cache in dev tools.

Comment: i adding url parameters to load new version after updated.

Comment: im pretty sure you cant do that there, you can only add parameters to the routes

Comment: okay so what is the solution when i deploy new version clear cache

Comment: if the user is on the site while you update it, they would have to refresh the page, unless you add something to your code to refresh for them

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro

Answer (score 1):

Remove the URL Parameters.
Add 
`--output-hashing=all`
to your build script.

`"build": "ng build --output-hashing=all"`

This will stop the cached versions loading.

Comment: `ng serve` is for testing, not for use in production

Comment: plus `ng serve` removes caching anyway

Comment: Edited, it works fine for build scripts too.
I was just using serve as my example.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. the only way for user to see changes in a lazy loaded module is to refresh the page.